# AWS Sagemaker | Why multiple instances training taking time multiplied to instance number

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS Sagemaker for model training and deployment, this is sample example for model training

```
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator
hyperparameters = {'train-steps': 10}
instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge'

estimator = Estimator(role=role,
                      train_instance_count=1,
                      train_instance_type=instance_type,
                      image_name=ecr_image,
                      hyperparameters=hyperparameters)

estimator.fit(data_location)
```

The docker image mentioned here is a tensorflow system.

Suppose it will take 1000 seconds to train the model, now I will increase the instance count to 5 then the training time will increase 5 times i.e. 5000 seconds. As per my understanding the training job will be distributed to 5 machines so ideally it will take 200 seconds per machine but seems its doing separate training on each machine. Can someone please let me know its working over distributed system in general or with Tensorflow.

I tried to find out the answer on this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sagemaker-dg.pdf but seems the way of working on distributed machines is not mentioned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [TensorFlow estimator APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimators) in your script? If yes, I think you should run the script by wrapping it in `sagemaker.tensorflow.TensorFlow` class as described [in the documentation here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst#training-with-tensorflow-estimator). If you run training that way, parallelization and communication between instances should work out-of-the-box.

But note that scaling will not be linear when you increase the number of instances. Communicating between instances takes time and there could be non-parallelizable bottlenecks in your script like loading data to memory.

Comment: no, we are not using Tensorflow estimator API rather core model fit like self.tf_prediction.eval(session=get_session()), not sure what is standard practice here

Comment: @Vineet What is your parallelization strategy then? Are you doing something similar to [Distributed TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)? I don't think you can train a vanilla TF script on multiple machines and assume they're automatically aware of each other. Perhaps you could try training on one big GPU instance instead of trying to use multiple instances?

Comment: I feel Sagemaker do all the parallelization at their end and we only need to pass instance count and type, even in case of custom container, Do we need to explicitly write all the stuff

Comment: SageMaker cannot automatically know how you want to parallelize arbitrary code to multiple machines. Even if it was aware that it's a TensorFlow training job and it could automatically make the machines aware of each other, assign them as workers or parameter servers, and decided to use "data parallel" strategy, it would still have to decide whether to do e.g. synchronous or asynchronous gradient updates (you can read more about those [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed)). I suggest you write your code using TF estimators and use SageMaker's TF containers.